# Положение символа `^` в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Простой вроде вопрос. Что означает регулярка `"a^b"` и можно ли ее найти в какой либо строке?

```
import re
p = re.compile("a^b")
p.search("ab") --> None
p.search("a^b") --> None
p.search("a\nb") --> None
```

Если такое выражение действительно не соответствует никакой строке (действительно, как может символ `a` встретиться *до начала* проверяемой строки), то почему оно вообще компилируется?

Или, перефразируя, меняется ли смысл символа `^`/`$` в зависимости от его положения в регулярном выражении (не внутри квадратных скобок)? Если нет, то почему?

Вопрос безотносительно ЯП, python просто примера ради.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`^` означает "начало строки" вне зависимости от того, в какой части выражения встретилось. Так же как и `$` - конец "строки". Но вот "начал" и "концов" в "строке" может быть несколько. Возьмем пример (на питоне, так на питоне):

```
import re
p=re.compile("a.*^b",re.M+re.S)
p.search("abc\nabcd")  --> None
p.search("abc\nbcd")   --> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='abc\nb'>
```

При компиляции выражения указаны флаги: `re.S` заставляет `.` соответствовать любым символам, включая перевод каретки. `re.M` заставляет рассматривать "строку", как "многострочную" - т.е. `^` начинает соответствовать не только началу данных, но и точке после любого перевода каретки. Вот мы и получили, что "a" встретился *до* начала строки.

Флаги можно задавать не только вторым параметром compile, но и внутри самой регулярки, конструкциями вроде `(?sm)`. Думаю разработчикам регулярок влом проводить такой глубокий анализ (Есть флаги, нет, а когда они начали действовать), ради выдачи ошибок вроде "начала строки тут быть не может". Собственно по этому никто и не рискует рассматривать `^ и $` по разному, в зависимости от положения (кроме случаев с квадратными скобками, конечно).

[Пример на regexp101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tY3aJ6/1)

Comment: внутри `[]` символ `^` Не означает начало строки :)

Comment: @Grundy цитата из вопроса ТС: _Или, перефразируя, меняется ли смысл символа ^/$ в зависимости от его положения в регулярном выражении (не внутри квадратных скобок)_. И под моим "в зависимости от положения" конечно имеется ввиду то же самое.

Comment: да :-) до этой части я не дочитал вопрос

Comment: @Mike, спасибо. Оказывается, я просто не сообразил поменять `a^b` на `a\\n^b` (грубо говоря). C `MULTILINE` то я я игрался.