# поиск подстроки в начале строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

как указать, что совпадение необходимо искать именно с начала строки?

например, искомое значение `hello`.
как сделать так, чтоб `world, hello` НЕ соответствовало поиску, а `hello world` соответствовало?

просто регулярному выражению `/hello/` соответствуют обе строки, а нужно, чтоб только вторая

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E5%E3%F3%EB%FF%F0%ED%FB%E5_%E2%FB%F0%E0%E6%E5%ED%E8%FF#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D0.B7.D0.B8.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.B2.D0.BD.D1.83.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B8_.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.BA.D0.B8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В регулярных выражениях существует несколько способов указания начала строки:

```
^
```

Данный *неэкранированный* "циркумфлекс", не находящийся сразу после неэкранированной открывающей квадратной скобки `[`, находит начало текста (string).

Однако в Ruby `^` находит только начало строки (line). Для нахождения начала всего текста, необходимо использовать

```
\A
```

Этот якорь можно использовать и в других языках/библиотеках регулярных выражений: в .NET, Python (re, regex), PHP (PCRE), Java, Swift/Objective-C (ICU).

Кстати, в текстовых редакторах, таких как Notepad++, `^` тоже использутеся для нахождения начала строки (line), а не всего текста.

Не путайте якорь `^` с другими функциями данного символа. См.

- [Регулярные выражение. Циркумфлекс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600062/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%A6%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81)
- [Положение символа `^` в регулярном выражении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548565/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8/548593#548593)